# symfony2 assert inheritance

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm working with Symfony2.
I have two classes: `employee` and `physician`. `doctor` is subclass of `employee`.

Entity `employee`:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Este valor ya se ha utilizado.")
```

When I uniqueentity valid email fields are validated only for employee and doctor separately.

If I insert employee3 `mail1@mail.com` error assert symfony2 work OK
If I insert doctor2 `mail3@mail.com` error assert symfony2 work OK
If I insert doctor2 `mail1@mail.com` show error sql but no error asserts symfony2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of the `UniqueEntityValidator` class:

```php
$repository = $em->getRepository($className);
$result = $repository->{$constraint->repositoryMethod}($criteria);

/* If the result is a MongoCursor, it must be advanced to the first
 * element. Rewinding should have no ill effect if $result is another
 * iterator implementation.
 */
if ($result instanceof \Iterator) {
    $result->rewind();
}

/* If no entity matched the query criteria or a single entity matched,
 * which is the same as the entity being validated, the criteria is
 * unique.
 */
if (0 === count($result) || (1 === count($result) && $entity === 
    ($result instanceof \Iterator ? $result->current() : current($result)))) {
    return;
}
```

As you can see, `$em->getRepository($className)` will be used as repository. The problem is that, without `repositoryMethod` option, Symfony will use the `findBy` method by Doctrine, available in every repository, even custom ones that inherits from `EntityRepository`.

When your entity is an `Employee`, Symfony will looking for an **existing entity with the given fields among employees only**:

```php
$em->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:Employee')->findBy($criteria);
```

The same happens when the entity is `Physician` (**looks only among physicians**):

```php
$em->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:Physician')->findBy($criteria);
```

Quoting you:

> If I insert employee3 mail1@mail.com error assert symfony2 work OK

That's because there is no employee with email mail1@mail.com

> If I insert doctor2 mail3@mail.com error assert symfony2 work OK

For the same reason as above.

> If I insert doctor2 mail1@mail.com show error sql but no error asserts
>   symfony2

Here is the problem! There is no physician with mail1@mail.com email! There is an employee with the same email, but when using `findBy` against physician repository, it returns `0`.

Maybe you should set the `repositoryMethod` option to a repository method that **will look for `employee` or `physician` when searching using an array as criteria**.